# Questions without upvote

Tags: discussion, questions, voting, up-votes

I'm writing this question because I love Stack Exchange, but I'm a little discouraged from what is happening recently :(

I'm making very **useful questions** and **the answers** the people give to me **are amazing**.
*But*...

The problem is (for me) that for the past *two months* I haven't received any upvote; conversely **those who respond have three upvotes easily**...

My questions are full of images and even GIF images to try to explain where my problem lies. I always try to make sure that they understand where the problem lies without having to make an effort to read my mind.

But it seems that everything is useless, because **no one gives me an upvote**.

Ok, I'm happy because I have an answer, ...**but if you answer the question, couldn't you also give me an upvote maybe?**

- So what could I do to have some upvotes?
- What changes have you made to make your questions more meaningful and pleasing to the answering audience?

All ideas are welcome. Also only to find out if you too are having this problem or not...

Thanks for the attention.

Comment: You might get better answers (for your specific situation) if you post this on https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/

Comment: ok thanks I will try to post it there, but it's also a generic questions, if you want to give an answer to the  last two questions

Comment: at least I am comforted to know that this situation is quite normal *shrug*

Comment: **Without knowing the context here and answering generally**I'll say that I don't always upvote a question if I answer it. In fact it's quite common for me to not vote at all or even downvote the question. Just because a question can be answered and shouldn't be closed doesn't mean it is a good question.

Comment: Without controversy, I would like to ask you when are you willing to vote on a question...  
I agree that actually an answer does not necessarily have to be an upvote to the question, but if we think about it, when should we appreciate a question?

Comment: See [How do comment replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) to learn to use @x to notify one non-sole non-poster commenter x re a comment. Owners & followers of posts always get notified. PS "when should we appreciate a question?" is addressed in site & meta site help centers. PS Ask 1 (specific researched non-duplicate question) per post. (Violated by the 1st question of yours I looked at.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> The problem is (for me) that it's since two month I haven't received any Upvote;
> conversely those who respond have 3 upvotes easily...

You've asked 4 questions in the past weeks on [graphic design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users/158553/lale), only 2 of them have answers that have a score of 3. So I would not claim 'those who respond have 3 upvotes easily'. There's very little data to make that claim, and 50 percent of answers reaching that isn't exactly 'easily'. If answers reached 3 votes easily, I would've expected to see a minimum of 3 votes on all answers there.

> but if you answer the question couldn't you also give me an upvote maybe?

Ideally, if you answer a question it *is* useful to have on the site, showing research effort and clear, and thus eligible for an upvote. Sadly, ideal circumstances rarely happen, and questions that lack either of those 3 criteria still get answered. So no, sadly someone that answers is not obliged to also upvote the question, just as they aren't obliged to actually vote down or close vote instead of answer.

> So what could I do to have some Upvotes?

Write questions that show research effort, are clear and most of all: are useful. If your questions are useful, they will be found by other people struggling with the same problems, and may be upvoted by them. Patience is a virtue here.

> What changes have you made to make your questions more meaningful and pleasing to the answering audience?

I've not resorted to any tricks, I just try to write questions to the best of my ability, and sometimes that's enough. At other times it isn't.

My experience on Interpersonal Skills is that you can try all you want and people will still find that 1 word that allows them to ignore your question, the limitations and the premise of it, and post an opinion on your usage of some words. If that happens, all you can do is accept you failed at writing a *clear* question.

On other sites, the crowds may be a bit easier or even worse. But I always try to just write a question to the best of my ability. There's only feedback on SE, and I can only get it after I've posted my question, so I just have to write and post stuff and see where it goes.

Comment: strict but fair, if patience is a virtue here, then I will have to cultivate it; Thank you for explaining your sad but truthful thought to me

Answer (score 5):

My honest advice to you is to worry a little less about getting upvotes.

You say:

> I'm making very useful question [sic] and the answers the people give to me are Amazing.

That's good. That's what Stack Exchange is for: asking questions that future visitors will want to know the answers to, and posting answers that will help those future visitors. Upvotes are merely the carrot on the stick that entice us to do that. They're not the primary goal of the site. As long as you're asking good questions and receiving good answers, upvotes don't really matter *that* much.

If your questions were receiving *down*votes, that would be a reason to be concerned, as it means your questions are considered "unclear or unhelpful", and too many downvotes can lead to a question ban. But as long as your questions are at least neutrally-scored and receiving good-quality answers, I'd say you have nothing to worry about.

Comment: So maybe I should review why I'm asking questions ... thanks, I had never seen it from this point of view